# How to run a task in MSBuild, only if files count are more than zero?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm trying to run a command in MSBuild, only if the condition is true. What condition? I count the files of a specific extension and if there is no file, I want to run that task.

```
<Target Name="MakeSureProjectHasViewsAndPagesInIt" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo PROJECT HAS NO CSHTML FILE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" Condition="dir *.cshtml /s" />
</Target>
```

I can't make the condition part work. I want to count all `*.cshtml` files in the current project's directory and subdirectories and if the result is zero, I want to run that command.

I'm stuck at how to write that condition. Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a property with the count of the files

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <CSHTMLCount>$([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)', '*.cshtml').Length)</CSHTMLCount>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MakeSureProjectHasViewsAndPagesInIt" Condition="'$(CSHTMLCount)' == '0'" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="echo PROJECT HAS NO CSHTML FILE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />
</Target>
```